# Dayanus taught at the 770 Central Yeshiva

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, chabad, yeshiva-school

Does anyone know what the Dayanus curriculum is taught at the 770 central Yeshiva today?

Comment: No clue, but it most likely includes the Halachos Choshen Mishpat written by the Alter Rebbe of Chabad.

Comment: Honestly, I'd reccommend contacting Yeshivas Tomchei Tmimim and asking them, as they would know the best. Their phone number is (718) 735-6601.

Comment: I understand there may be no standard curriculum. But what is the set curriculum by 770. I recall on Collive or Chabad.info. Rabbi Labkowsky giving תעודת דיינות. If someone could call Tomchei Tmimim I would very grateful as for some reason nobody has got back to me. Please let me know on this forum. Have a good Shabbos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Orach Chaim:** Krias Sefer Torah, Netilas Yodaim, Betzias Hapas, Brachos Shebiseudah, Mayim Achronim, Birkas Hamazon, Birkas Hapeiros, Seder Birkas Hanehenin, Shabbos and Eiruvin.

**Yoreh Deah:** Melicha, Basar Bechalav, Taarovos, Maacholei Akum, Hechsher Keilim, Nosen Taam Lipgam, Ribis and Mikvaos.

**Even Haezer:** Priyah Urviah (Yuchsin and Agunos), Kidushin and Gittin.

**Choshen Mishpat:** Dayanim, Eidus, Toen Venitan and Nachalos.
As well as portions of various Seforim relevant to the above topics.

https://anash.org/three-ordained-by-770s-demanding-dayanus-program/

Comment: No Hilchos Nidah?

Comment: @Charzkel I thought that as well. They may discuss it as part of Hilchos mikvaos.

Comment: @Chatzkel they have said the course is mainly geared towards bochurim in regards to omission of Hilchos Nidah